# Не могу понять работу генератора списка

Tags: python, факторизация

На [странице](https://stackoverrun.com/ru/q/3331804) расписано как найти все делители числа, вычислив простую факторизацию. Там указана вот эта функция.
Мне не понятна строка: `div = [d * p**e for d in div for e in range(r + 1)]` из за двойного цикла.
Можно ли развернуть эту запись в несколько строк чтобы я мог провести трассировку и самостоятельно разобраться в работе. 
P.S.Еще изучаю питон и некоторые хитрые семантические выверты мне не понятны.

```
def divisors(factors):
       div = [1]
       for (p, r) in factors:
           div = [d * p**e for d in div for e in range(r + 1)]
       return div
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Данная строка не то что бы эквивалентна блоку ниже, но приносит тот же результат

```
div = []
for e in range(r+1):
    for d in div:
        div.append(d * p**e)
```

Конструкция, которую вы продемонстрировали, называется генератором списка. Используется таким образом:

Допустим, у нас есть список `arr_to_copy`, элементы из которого надо перенести в новый список `result_array`, умножив каждый из них при этом на `5`

```
result_array = [eachElem*5 for eachElem in arr_to_copy ]
```

Разбирая ваш пример:

```
div = [d * p**e for d in div for e in range(r + 1)]
```

1) Квадратные скобки говорят о том, что тип данных переменной `div` - это [] (list)

2) Внутри скобок описаны значения его переменных, а именно...

3) `for e in range(r+1)` - итерируем range(r+1) для вычисления каждого элемента `div`. Для этого используем значение `e`

4) Далее, внутри итерации в пункте 3, итерируем `for d in div`, таким образом организуя двойной цикл

5) В левой части скобок находится выражение, которому будет равен каждый элемент списка `div` по порядку на каждом шаге итерации. `d * p**e`

Надеюсь, я объяснил всё предельно ясно. Если у вас остались вопросы, задайте их в комментарии и я постараюсь ответить, отредактировав этот ответ.

Comment: Код не рабочий (x2).